# Aerospike not starting

Tags: aerospike

My aerospike nodes do not come back from restarts with the following logs:

```
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::161) SIGSEGV received, aborting Aerospike Community Edition build 3.7.2 os ubuntu12.04
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: found 7 frames
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 0: /usr/bin/asd(as_sig_handle_segv+0x5d) [0x48a1d6]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cc0) [0x7f10fb8d0cc0]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 2: /usr/bin/asd(build_service_list+0x40) [0x4ab065]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 3: /usr/bin/asd(as_config_post_process+0x304) [0x4685bd]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 4: /usr/bin/asd(main+0x228) [0x45fd08]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f10fb8bbf45]
Jun 07 2016 20:56:23 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::163) stacktrace: frame 6: /usr/bin/asd() [0x4608a9]

(gdb) info line *0x48a1d6
Line 163 of "base/signal.c" starts at address 0x48a1c7 <as_sig_handle_segv+78> and ends at 0x48a25e <as_sig_handle_segv+229>.
(gdb) info line *0x7efcdb681cc0
No line number information available for address 0x7efcdb681cc0
(gdb) info line *0x4ab065
Line 5479 of "base/thr_info.c" starts at address 0x4ab065 <build_service_list+64> and ends at 0x4ab06c <build_service_list+71>.
(gdb) info line *0x4685bd
Line 3338 of "base/cfg.c" starts at address 0x4685bd <as_config_post_process+772> and ends at 0x4685ca <as_config_post_process+785>.
(gdb) info line *0x45fd08
Line 416 of "base/as.c" starts at address 0x45fd08 <main+552> and ends at 0x45fd11 <main+561>.
(gdb) info line *0x7efcdb66cf45
No line number information available for address 0x7efcdb66cf45
(gdb) info line *0x4608a9
No line number information available for address 0x4608a9 <_start+41>
```

Clearing everything up and setting up node from scratch doesn't help. i net command shows failed nodes but I can't remove them as this operation [requires](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-remove-an-offline-node-in-aerospike-aer-2757-released-resolved/1472) a rolling restart – and nodes do not start after being stopped.

How can I figure out why does aerospike fail to start?

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
Line 5479 of "base/thr_info.c" starts at address 0x4ab065 <build_service_list+64> and ends at 0x4ab06c <build_service_list+71>.
```

Goes [here](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/blob/3.7.2/as/src/base/thr_info.c#L5479). I had 254 aliases on the internal interface. Removed 253 of them and now aerospike starts fine.